# While keeping cursor on user pop up is coming

Tags: discussion, support, tags

While keeping the cursor on some users a pop up is coming.

Why is it showing? Is there some specific reason that they should have more reputation in Stack Overflow or more badges?

Also I saw some users having less reputation also showing pop up.

Can anyone explain this feature for me?

Comment: Are you talking about the [Expanded Usercard](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)?

Comment: yes @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about expanded user card which opens up on 1k reputation as user privilege.

From [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on
>   the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded
>   usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a
>   hover card.

For card to appear you need to have some profile info in you profile section.

If user don't want to show card they can use,

> If you have a long profile About Me, but don't want there to be an
>   expanded usercard for any reason, you can use the summary comment with
>   an insufficiently long passage to render your profile as "too short"
>   for display. For example, the following will be considered too short.
>
> ```
> <!-- summary: &nbsp; -->
> ```

But still it opens up on 1k rep not lower than that.